# Reenabling document.execCommand("cut") in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webos, enyo

Is there a way to re-enable the `document.execCommand("cut")` Javascript method call in Google Chrome?  Palm's WebOS Enyo framework uses this is a few places, which means when I'm working on applications locally I can't access every API of the framework.

Insight from all platforms welcome, but I'm working on OS X so those answers are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to use the emulator for some functionality.

I dont know if other WebKit browsers like Safari have this ability enabled however.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome does not support execCommand or clipboard interaction, which is considered a security threat.

For example, Google docs on chrome shows a "Please use CTRL+X or use your browser's edit menu" dialog when a user tries to execute cut from google docs' UI.

An experimental clipboard API is available for chrome **extensions**: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.clipboard.html#method-executeCut